# Disabling Submit-button(s) when HTML Select is empty

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I am a programmer-to-be, currently working on a project at work.

My problem is this: I have 3 submit buttons (on the same form), that each call a different action. These buttons **HAVE** to be disabled, if the `HTML Selector` (dropdown) does not have any options to choose from.

My form currently looks like this:

```
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
        <div class="col-md-9">

            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label asp-for="OrderNumber">Order number: </label>
                <input asp-for="OrderNumber" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Insert order number" autofocus />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Delete</label>
                <input asp-for="Deletion" type="checkbox" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Receive" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Start" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Finish" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label asp-for="ProfileId">Profile: </label>
                <select asp-for="ProfileId" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var p in Model.Profiles)
                    {
                        <option value="@p.ProfileId">@p.Name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks for any help, and if you need more information, or if this question is poorly described, do not hesitate to ask! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution of my own using Razor.

My form now looks like this:

```
        <form asp-action="Index" method="post" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label asp-for="OrderNumber">Order number: </label>
                <input asp-for="OrderNumber" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Insert order number" autofocus />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Delete</label>
                <input asp-for="Deletion" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Receive"
                           @{ if (Model.Profiles.Count() == 0) { @: disabled="disabled"
                                                                                       } } />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Start"
                           @{ if (Model.Profiles.Count() == 0) { @: disabled="disabled"
                                                                                       } } />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="action" value="Finish"
                           @{ if (Model.Profiles.Count() == 0) { @: disabled="disabled"
                                                                                       } } />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
                <label asp-for="ProfileId">Profile: </label>
                <select asp-for="ProfileId" class="form-control">
                    @foreach (var p in Model.Profiles)
                    {
                        <option value="@p.ProfileId">@p.Name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I added an if-statement, that checks if there is any profiles in my list of profiles. If there is none (0), it adds the *disabled="disabled"* attribute to my inputs.

Thanks to anyone that tried to assist me in solving this, and providing me with suggestions for a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Give your buttons an id. Set them to be disabled (enabled="false").

Call a javascript function when the dropdownlist is changed.

Check the selectedIndex of the dropdownlist in the function that is called onchange and set the button accordingly.

I could write a function that would do it, but you wouldn't learn anything. If you do a bit of research, have a stab at writing the function, I'll fix it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough, or I am misunderstanding your response. They should be disabled if the html select has no values to select from (if Model.Profiles has no profiles in it).

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable the form fields that need be depending on if the others have the same conditional requirements. You can give them a custom class and use some javascript code and toggle the class with some JS like so.

```
toggleAttribute = function(className,index){
      var eLs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(className),0);
      for(var i=0; i<eLs.length; i++){
         eLs[i].disabled=(index==0 ? false : true); //index 0 is for 'Yes'
      }
}
```

Comment: Simply disabling the forms fields using javascript code, is easier said than done for me. I have no previous experience with JavaScripting.

I know that this is not javascript, but would something along the lines of:

'@if (Model.Profiles == null)
{
buttons.enabled = false;
}'

where buttons would be the id or a class assigned to these buttons?

Comment: Good day. You want to use the method mentioned by Martin and that is add enabled="false" to the ones you need disabled, or you can add a class and use display:none and then based on that class name, use that class name for the JS code I posted. Also, C# and JS have many similarities..